# system.assertException - assertion failed

Tags: apex, unit-test, visualforce-component

I'm getting the below error when i deploy the apex class, how can I solve it:

> RELVSRenewalControllerTest    testLoadChildDataCurrent    System.AssertException:
>   Assertion Failed: Expected: 4, Actual: 6  Stack Trace:
>   Class.RELVSRenewalControllerTest.testLoadChildDataCurrent: line 173,
>   column 1
>
> RELVSRenewalControllerTest    testaddContactObject    System.AssertException:
>   Assertion Failed: Expected: 6, Actual: 8  Stack Trace:
>   Class.RELVSRenewalControllerTest.testaddContactObject: line 351,
>   column 1

Here is my test class:

```
     @isTest static void testLoadChildDataCurrent() {
        try {
            Test.startTest();

            Integer assertCountDBATotal = 0;
            Integer assertCountContactCurrent = 0;

            Id p = [select id from profile where name = 'REL VSA Community User'].id;
            //System.debug('P into test routine - ' + p);
            UserRole userrole = [Select id, name from userrole where portalType = 'None' limit 1];
            List<Contact> aCommunityContactList = [select ID, lastName from contact where lastName like '%Community%'];
            //System.debug('# of contacts - ' + aCommunityContactList.size());
            List<User> aUserList = new List<User> ();
            For (Contact aCommunityUser : aCommunityContactList) {
                //system.debug('Account Id - ' + aCommunityUser.AccountId);
                aUserList.add(new User(alias = aCommunityUser.LastName.right(8), email = aCommunityUser.LastName + '@noemail.com',
                                       emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = aCommunityUser.LastName, languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                                       localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p, country = 'United States', IsActive = true,
                                       ContactId = aCommunityUser.Id, //userroleid=userrole.id,
                                       timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = aCommunityUser.LastName.right(8) + '@noemail.com'));
            }
            insert(aUserList);

            List<User> myTestUsers = [SELECT id, Name From user where email like '%@noemail.com%'];
            system.debug('# of users = ' + myTestUsers.size());



            For (User myTestUser : myTestUsers) {
                //System.debug('myTester: ' + myTestUser + myTestUser.Name);
                system.runAs(myTestUser) {
                    //Remove - todo
                    List<Contact> tempContactList = [select id from contact];
                    system.debug('Plain contact query count - ' + tempContactList.size());
                    //Remove - todo - end
                    ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id = :Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;
                    ID aAccountID = [Select AccountID from Contact where id = :contactid].AccountId;
                    system.debug('Account ID Processed for ' + myTestUser.Name + ' is ' + aAccountID);
                    List<REL_VS_Submission__c> myTestSubmissions = [SELECT id From REL_VS_Submission__c where REL_VS_Account__c = :aAccountID];
                    PageReference pageRef = Page.RELVSRenewal1;
                    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
                    ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestSubmissions[0]);
                    RELVSRenewalController atestcontroller = new RELVSRenewalController(sc);
                    system.debug('myTestUsers - ' + myTestUsers.size());
                    system.debug('DBA size returned by CC - ' + atestcontroller.anewDBA.size());
                    system.debug('DBA assertCountDBATotal - ' + assertCountDBATotal);
                    assertCountDBATotal = assertCountDBATotal + atestcontroller.anewDBA.size();
                     system.debug('DBA assertCountDBATotal - ' + assertCountDBATotal);
                    assertCountContactCurrent = assertCountContactCurrent + atestcontroller.anewContact.size();
 system.debug('DBA assertCountDBATotal - ' + assertCountContactCurrent);

                }
            }
               system.debug('DBA assertCountDBATotal - ' + assertCountDBATotal);
            system.debug('DBA assertCountDBATotal - ' + assertCountContactCurrent);
            system.debug('$$$$$BEFORE ASSERT$$$$$');
            System.assertEquals(4, assertCountDBATotal);
            System.assertEquals(4, assertCountContactCurrent);


            Test.stopTest();


        }

        catch(Exception e) {

            throw e;
        }

    }

       @IsTest static void testaddContactObject() {
    Integer assertCountContactCurrent = 0;
    try {
        System.debug('inside testclass - addContactObject');
        Id p = [select id from profile where name = 'REL VSA Community User'].id;
        //System.debug('P into test routine - ' + p);
        UserRole userrole = [Select id, name from userrole where portalType = 'None' limit 1];
        List<Contact> aCommunityContactList = [select ID, lastName from contact where lastName like '%Community%'];
        //System.debug('# of contacts - ' + aCommunityContactList.size());
        List<User> aUserList = new List<User> ();
        For (Contact aCommunityUser : aCommunityContactList) {
            //system.debug('Account Id - ' + aCommunityUser.AccountId);
            aUserList.add(new User(alias = aCommunityUser.LastName.right(8), email = aCommunityUser.LastName + '@noemail.com',
                                   emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = aCommunityUser.LastName, languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                                   localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p, country = 'United States', IsActive = true,
                                   ContactId = aCommunityUser.Id, //userroleid=userrole.id,
                                   timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = aCommunityUser.LastName.right(8) + '@noemail.com'));
        }
        insert(aUserList);

        List<User> myTestUsers = [SELECT id, Name From user where email like '%@noemail.com%'];
        system.debug('# of users = ' + myTestUsers.size());



        For (User myTestUser : myTestUsers) {
            //System.debug('myTester: ' + myTestUser + myTestUser.Name);
            system.runAs(myTestUser) {
                //Remove - todo
                List<Contact> tempContactList = [select id from contact];
                system.debug('Plain contact query count - ' + tempContactList.size());
                //Remove - todo - end
                ID contactId = [Select contactid from User where id = :Userinfo.getUserid()].contactId;
                ID aAccountID = [Select AccountID from Contact where id = :contactid].AccountId;
                system.debug('Account ID Processed for ' + myTestUser.Name + ' is ' + aAccountID);
                List<REL_VS_Submission__c> myTestSubmissions = [SELECT id From REL_VS_Submission__c where REL_VS_Account__c = :aAccountID];
                PageReference pageRef = Page.RELVSRenewal1;
                Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
                ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestSubmissions[0]);
                RELVSRenewalController atestcontroller = new RELVSRenewalController(sc);
                atestcontroller.addContactObject();
                system.debug('Contact size returned by CC addContactObject - ' + atestcontroller.anewContact.size());
                assertCountContactCurrent = assertCountContactCurrent + atestcontroller.anewContact.size();

            }
        }
        System.assertEquals(8, assertCountContactCurrent);

    }

    catch(Exception e) {

        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is only one test case from your test class, which has two failing assertions. It will be very difficult to troubleshoot your assertion failures without a better reproducible example: the *relevant portions* of your code being tested, a *clear* unit test with explanation of what it is doing, and the results.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me . I have added the other test class which is also failing.

Comment: @Arnav we also need the code the test is testing, otherwise we won't be able to understand what exactly the code is doing under the surface. Try to narrow it down if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *assertion* means you are asserting (stating) that a condition is true.  If the condition is not true, the assertion will throw an uncatchable exception. That's what is happening.  Consider the first error message:

> RELVSRenewalControllerTest testLoadChildDataCurrent System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 4, Actual: 6 Stack Trace: Class.RELVSRenewalControllerTest.testLoadChildDataCurrent: line 173, column 1

breaking this down:

> RELVSRenewalControllerTest testLoadChildDataCurrent

Something happened in `RELVSRenewalControllerTest.testLoadChildDataCurrent`, which is the first test method you listed above.

> System.AssertException

This is the class name of the Assertion that was thrown.  All exceptions in Apex are instances of a class the derives from `System.Exception`.  Whenever you call any of the `System.Assert*` methods (`assert`, `assertEquals`, etc,), if the assertion fails (is not true), this exception is thrown.  This is the primary means of unit testing in Apex: you call your code, and *assert* that you get an expected result.

> Expected: 4, Actual: 6

This is the detail of how the assertion failed.  You have two assertions in the given test method (we'll talk about how to know which one failed below):

```
System.assertEquals(4, assertCountDBATotal);
System.assertEquals(4, assertCountContactCurrent);
```

Each one asserts that a value from your test code will equal 4.  The error message states that an assertion was made and the expected value was 4, but the actual value seen was 6.  So either `assertCountDBATotal` or `assertCountContactCurrent` equaled 6 when the relevant assertion was called.

> Stack Trace: Class.RELVSRenewalControllerTest.testLoadChildDataCurrent: line 173, column 1

The final part of an exception message is the Stack Trace; this shows what line of code failed, and if applicable, which line(s) of code called the failing line.  Here we see that the code failed on line 173.  If you check your test class in Developer Console (or an IDE with line numbers), you will find one of the assertions listed above is on line 173.  That's where the failure is.

So, why is your code failing?  That cannot be answered solely by looking at your test class.  You need to look at which assertion failed, then figure out which part of your code provided that value, and then figure out why it was wrong.  It may be worth validating your expected value (4) as well.  It looks like you have plenty of debugging statements, so I'm guessing you already know how the code works, and you've walked through this before.

You asked, "I'm getting the below error **when i deploy** the apex class".  Is the test passing in a dev sandbox, but failing in the target org (where ever you are trying to deploy)?  If so, then there is a difference between the source and the target org data.  This shouldn't cause an issue if you are isolating your tests from org data.

I don't see any code in the test to create the users you are searching for; Is your test class annotated with `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)`?  If so, that's probably the source of your issues - the users in the target org are different than in the original org.

Instead of using `seealldata=true`, you should use `seealldata=false` (or remove `seealldata`, same thing) and create the users you need for your unit test inside the test method, or in a `@TestSetup` method.  See [Understanding Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data.htm?search_text=Database.Batchable) in the Apex Developer's Guide for details.